# Loading STL with Three.js r69 switching to r73 causes error

Tags: three.js

I have some problems with the version switching of three.js .

I used to use these codes to load an stl file in three.js r69:

```
  var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
     function initLoad() {
     loader.addEventListener('load', function (event) {

     var geometryOfFiles = event.content;
     var materialOfFiles = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
     wrapAround: true,
     wrapRGB: new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 1),
     color: 0xFFFFFF,
     specular: 0xFFFFFF,
     shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
     shininess: 630,
     fog: false,
     side: THREE.DoubleSide

     });
     var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometryOfFiles, materialOfFiles);

     object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
     object.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI / 111);
     object.scale.set(2, 2, 2);


     scene.add(object);


     });
     loader.load('miku.stl');
     }
```

But when I use the above in r73, I got this error message in browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: loader.addEventListener is not a function
```

I didn't change anything in my file except the js version.It seems some method or function has been changed in r73.

Comment: Did you check the three.js [example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html) or read the comments at the top of the `STLLoader.js` source file?